# Transient list does not disappear when the entity is loaded from the database

Tags: java, java-ee-7

Ok i have a Entity with a transient list like below,

```
@Entity
public class PedidoProduto extends Entidade implements Serializable {


@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
private long id;
...
private transient List<Extra> extras = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

if the list is initialized like this when i load the entity from the database, the previous values from the transient list are still there, what is this? a bug? shoudn't all transient values disappear?

if the field is like this

```
private transient List<Extra> extras;
```

everything works fine.

i am using java 8 + eclipselink + jboss eap.

link for the project below

[testProject](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqN1TKPodnoGgtpxdiakKaprZYsxTA)

```
@Named
@ViewScoped

public class TestBean implements Serializable {
@Inject
private EntityDAO entityDAO;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8956817909680352424L;

public void init1() {
    try {
        EntityA entityA = new EntityA();
        entityA.getEntityBs().add(new EntityB());
        entityA.getEntityBs().add(new EntityB());
        entityDAO.persist(entityA);
        List<EntityB> entityBs = entityA.getEntityBs();
        for (EntityB entityB : entityBs) {
            entityB.setEntityA(entityA);
            entityDAO.persist(entityB);
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index2.xhtml");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void init2() {
    try {
        List<EntityA> list = entityDAO.list();
        System.out.println(list.get(0).getEntityBs().size());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}


@Stateless 

public class EntityDAO implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8737155205806078582L;
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void persist(Object object) {
    entityManager.persist(object);
}

public List<EntityA> list() {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<EntityA> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(EntityA.class);
    TypedQuery<EntityA> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<EntityA> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
    System.out.println(resultList.get(0).getEntityBs().size());
    return resultList;
}
}

@Entity

public class EntityA implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1111059735979895196L;
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
private long id;
private int a;
private transient List<EntityB> entityBs = new ArrayList<EntityB>();

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EntityA [id=" + id + "]";
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    EntityA other = (EntityA) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public List<EntityB> getEntityBs() {
    return entityBs;
}

public void setEntityBs(List<EntityB> entityBs) {
    this.entityBs = entityBs;
}
}

@Entity

public class EntityB implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2415887620867648666L;
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
private long id;
private EntityA entityA;
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EntityB [id=" + id + "]";
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    EntityB other = (EntityB) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public EntityA getEntityA() {
    return entityA;
}

public void setEntityA(EntityA entityA) {
    this.entityA = entityA;
}

}
```

index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
<h:head  >
</h:head>
<h:body  >
#{testBean.init1()}
</h:body>
</html>
```

index2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
<h:head  >
</h:head>
<h:body  >
#{testBean.init2()}
 </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the code loading the entity? Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: I put a test project on my onedrive, you can download it

Comment: I won't. Put the relevant code in your question.

Comment: ok , and i will record a video too

Comment: No, that's useless.

Comment: done, the code is there

Comment: When and how are init1 and init2 invoked? If they are invoked in the same transaction, it's perfectly normal for the list to still be there: you persist your entity and populate its list, then you execute a query returning that entity, so you get it back.

Comment: init1 is invoked on index.xhtml then the page is redirected to index2.xhtml and the init2 is invoked

Comment: the transaction ends when init1 ends